# MVC File upload random fails

Tags: file, model-view-controller, upload

I've been working on a MVC project which includes uploading files. I cannot quite figure this one out.

I've configured so that I can upload ~1GB per file, now we're talking about a small image, say 0.05MB that I'm trying to upload. About ~30% av all times i get thrown to the error page in my project, I've notices that I can still have a perfect connection while uploading.

The problem **only** occurs on iPhone/iPad so far. When I choose to upload a file it works sometimes, and sometimes not. I see no specific patterns for failure, except that I get thrown to the error page, and that happens when a page/file cannot be found in my project.

I cannot debug this with breakpoints easily since the problem only occur on wireless devices (iPhone/iPad) when the project is published online. I've checked all the Views and all "return function" in the code and see no errors.

I've tried adding new values in web.config but without success (eg. executionTimeout)I've also set the web.config to accept files up to ~1GB.

As I've said, the upload process fails randomly, even if I repeat the procedure in the exact same order.

What do you think I should do, any idea what to try? Can I debug on my iPad, that would have helped me. I did install Safari for Windows, no result.

Building in VS2015.

Thank you very much!
Regards

**Edit:**

I've been struggling to prevent the default error message page with a custom made one (if uploaded file not found) and entered this line into Web.config:

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/files/*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

But since I'm not exactly sure what it does more than gives me my beautiful error page it also seems to prevent some files to be uploaded. Since I removed this line from Web.config **it seems to work for the moment**, if we can count on chance...

Comment: You need to figure out what the error is. If the site is showing you the error page, then what does it contain? If you are hiding errors as it's on  production box, then check the Windows logs, or use a tool like [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Comment: I'm working on it, well the error page is custom made (by me) and shows no technical data what so ever. Elmah was new to me, I'll check that out, thank you very much.